# Command+Z stopped working in all applications

Tags: keyboard, undo-redo

My <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> stopped working. In any app. Including keyboard viewer.

Neither Left nor Right Command.

It's not hardware – <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> (or <kbd>Command</kbd> + any other modifier) works on both sides.

It's like something is 'trapping' that combo. What could it be? I quit [Butler](http://manytricks.com/butler/); that was the only shortcut app I had.

### Update

Strange … if I go to Keyboard Pref Panel > Shortcuts, and 'Add' an All Applications shortcut for Undo, then in that little window I **can** enter <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>. But it still does not work anywhere else!

Answer (score 2):

Whew! Found it!
It was an errant hotkey in [Synergy](http://synergy-project.org/synergy/).

Had to go through every running app one by one and look for hot key settings.

Answer (score 0):

Command + Z is assigned to Zoom. Change this in
System Settings -> Keyboard -> Keyboard Shortcuts -> App Shortcuts -> All Applications -> Zoom.
I set this to Command + "+". This enabled Command + "Z" to function as Undo.